# Limits of 2 functions

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limits of the following.
$$ 2/(1-x^2) - 1/(1-x)\, \text{ as x tends to 1}$$
    .
I tried joining them and apply L rule and I got $0.5$.

I want to try to do it the other way.

Let $f(x) = \frac{2}{1-x^2}$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$

$$\lim(f(x) - g(x)) = \lim(f(x)) - \lim(g(x))$$

Cant I do this way? As in i don't know how to solve $\lim f(x)$ alone.

Comment: No, you cannot split the limits since neither exists independently.

Comment: combine two fractions together before taking limit.

Comment: When you "join" them (common denominator) you get cancellation, it simplifies to $\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of exercises like these are to first get you comfortable with algebra, but they also provide interesting examples which illustrate that the limit of a difference (sum) is not always the difference (sum) of the limits.

> With the in mind, notice that $\frac{2}{1-x^2} = f(x)$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ are not defined at $x = 1$. And further, in the case of $g(x)$, the closer and closer $x$ is to $1$, the larger the magnitude of $g$ is. Precisely, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} g(x)= -\infty, \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} g(x) = \infty$$
>   However, after some algebraic manipulation, we see that 
>   $$f(x) - g(x) = \frac{2}{(1-x)(1+x)} - \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{2}{(1-x)(1+x)} - \frac{(1+x)}{(1+x)(1-x)}$$
>   further, 
>   $$\frac{2}{(1-x)(1+x)} - \frac{(1+x)}{(1+x)(1-x)} = \frac{1 - x}{(1+x)(1-x)} = \frac{1}{1+x}$$
>   which is continuous at $x = 1$ and so $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\big( {f(x) - g(x) } \big)= 1/2 $$